# How do I open the folder with my renders from the Blender UI?

Tags: rendering, interface, osx

In previous versions of **Blender**, I could click on `OPT` + `the folder icon` in the **Output** section of the **Output Properties** and it would open the folder in the Mac's Finder.

In Blender 2.90, clicking `OPT` + `the folder icon` does absolutely nothing.
I've searched online and couldn't find what has changed or how to quickly open the folder.

Comment: In MS Windows a tool tip shows other options.  Do you have such a tooltip??

Comment: I don’t know what that means. On Mac only up/down arrows appear that make you move the panel up or down

Comment: In the Blender UI ... next to the name of the folder I see a little icon of a folder .  When I hover pause the mouse over this icon it shows me keystrokes to go with the click, such as SHIFT or ALT.

Comment: Ok atomic, that solved it. They changed the shortcut to SHIFT + Click the . When I hovered it made a label appear that suggested that. You can make your comment into an answer if you want, keeping in mind that I was asking for Mac 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Blender UI ... next to the name of the folder I see a little icon of a folder .  The folder will have a tooltip or shortcut when you hover your pointing device ️.

The short cut or tool tip will read something such as
SHIFT + Click the

giving the keystrokes on your Mac OSX